# Tokio thread management: restart subsidiary thread from inside encapsulating thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio

```rust
use tokio;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};
use std::time::{UNIX_EPOCH, SystemTime};
use anyhow::{Result, Error};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let task1 = tokio::spawn(async move{
        loop{
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(3)).await;
            let now = SystemTime::now()
                        .duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH)?
                        .as_millis();
            if now as u128 % 9 == 0 {
                //on >2 iterations here,
                //if "task2" is running
                //task2 should be terminated
                //and the block below executed again
                let task2 = tokio::spawn(async move{
                    println!("abc");
                    println!("cde");
                    println!("erg");
                });
                //how to join task 2 here 
                //so that task1 isn't blocked?
            };
        }; Ok::<(), Error>(())
    });
    tokio::join![task1];
    Ok(())
}
```

[[ PLAYGROUND ]](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eb6b156931136e3b51e87deb216257f3)

I need to run 2 or more threads:

- [controller thread] `loop{}` a 'timer' thread that's controlling the flow of my program,
- [helper thread] operates on the data that thread 1 provides, singular execution or `loop{}`

If `task1` conditions are met, data has changed and I need to abort `task2`. There is no need for it to operate on the old data, instead it has to be restarted.

I've found solutions such as:
`task.abort();`
however, this could make my code a total mess, but I've used it in my Playground example nonetheless (can't figure out how to implement it there without `task2` being external to `task1`).

Ideally, I'd love to somehow declare `task2` outside of the body of `task1` with a handle specifying whether an instance is currently running, and control it based on that.

Still, this is already 3-4 levels of indentation before I even started typing out any code and it bothers me.

My inquiries:

- is there any method allowing for a declaration of a block to spawn that's reusable so that a restart is less messy?
- is there a direct method or set thereof allowing for a smooth restarting threads in a program's architecture?

What's required is `.abort()` + running same thread from start.

Comment: I think you are mixing up *tasks* and *threads* here. Those are very important concepts and understanding the differences is crucial for async programming.

Comment: Minor nitpick: the modulo (`%`) operation is really not suited for durations. Please use `>` or `>=` instead. There could always be a random lag and you could jump over the modulo condition.

Comment: The reason why you get so many indentations is because you use `async {}` for spawning your tasks. Use `async fn`'s instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways of cancelling a task:

- gracefully, via something like a `CancellationToken`
- forcefully, via `.abort()`.

Here is one possible solution for a graceful cancellation:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use tokio;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};
use tokio_util::sync::CancellationToken;

async fn task2(value: u32, cancellation_token: CancellationToken) {
    'outer: loop {
        for msg in ["abc", "cde", "erg"] {
            println!("task2: {} {}", msg, value);

            tokio::select! {
                _ = sleep(Duration::from_millis(500)) => {},
                _ = cancellation_token.cancelled() => break 'outer,
            };
        }
    }
}

async fn task1() -> Result<()> {
    let mut value = 42;
    let mut task2_cancellation_token = CancellationToken::new();
    let mut task2_handle = tokio::spawn(task2(value, task2_cancellation_token.clone()));

    let mut iteration = 0;
    loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(300)).await;
        iteration += 1;
        if iteration % 9 == 0 {
            println!("Cancelling task2 ...");
            task2_cancellation_token.cancel();
            println!("Waiting for task2 to finish ...");
            task2_handle.await?;

            println!("Updating value ...");
            value += 1;

            println!("Restarting task2 ...");
            task2_cancellation_token = CancellationToken::new();
            task2_handle = tokio::spawn(task2(value, task2_cancellation_token.clone()));
        };
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    task1().await
}
```

```
task2: abc 42
task2: cde 42
task2: erg 42
task2: abc 42
task2: cde 42
task2: erg 42
Cancelling task2 ...
Waiting for task2 to finish ...
Updating value ...
Restarting task2 ...
task2: abc 43
task2: cde 43
task2: erg 43
...
```

Alternatively, this is forcefully via `.abort()`:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use tokio;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};

async fn task2(value: u32) {
    loop {
        for msg in ["abc", "cde", "erg"] {
            println!("task2: {} {}", msg, value);
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(500)).await;
        }
    }
}

async fn task1() -> Result<()> {
    let mut value = 42;
    let mut task2_handle = tokio::spawn(task2(value));

    let mut iteration = 0;
    loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(300)).await;
        iteration += 1;
        if iteration % 9 == 0 {
            println!("Aborting task2 ...");
            task2_handle.abort();
            // Ignore return value, as it will most likely
            // be a cancelled `JoinError`.
            task2_handle.await.ok();

            println!("Updating value ...");
            value += 1;

            println!("Restarting task2 ...");
            task2_handle = tokio::spawn(task2(value));
        };
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    task1().await
}
```

```
task2: abc 42
task2: cde 42
task2: erg 42
task2: abc 42
task2: cde 42
task2: erg 42
Aborting task2 ...
Updating value ...
Restarting task2 ...
task2: abc 43
task2: cde 43
task2: erg 43
...
```

---

### Advantages and disadvantages

Graceful cancellation is harder to implement correctly. So if your task permits it, `abort()` is easier and doesn't require any additional code in the cancelled task.

That said, the task has no way to react to `abort()`. If your task can only be cancelled in specific states, or it has to run some shutdown functionality on cancellation, a graceful shutdown is the only possibility.

Comment: While implementing this solution, I've moved ownership of my complex data structures into `fn1` since it's an endless loop, then use them as borrowed values for spawning `fn2` each time -> getting numerous errors as in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a1379b999cf2c4e4868abeaf47ee724a). I've solved it with `.clone()` but is there a faster solution allowing for me to specify that the `fn1` doesn't ever really drop the values?

Comment: Sadly, not really... The only think I can think about is moving it in and out. Async tasks could be run by an executor on a different thread, and Rust has no idea how long it will live. So no, you can't tell it because you don't know how long it lives either. An external "abort" could kill the main task while leaving the other two running, causing a dangling reference. You can only pass `'static` references or owned values to an async fn. That's just how it is.

Comment: That said, you could wrap it in an `Arc<tokio::sync::Mutex<...>>`. That should work.

Comment: @tommy1213 Like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=49ccc7f1bd20790b474cb358f82573c6